# How to replace multiple space with a single comma in TCL

Tags: tcl

Please tell me way to replace multiple spaces with comma for example input string

```
set string "boy      cat dog            girl     man"
```

there can be multiple space between the strings example 8 betwee boy and cat , 4 between dog and girl

and i want it as `boy,cat,dog,girl,man`

Answer (score 9):

It's really easy: you only have to use `regsub`, which performs substitutions based on regular expressions.

```
set string "boy     cat   dog  girls man"
regsub -all {\s+} $string ,
```

and you get

```
boy,cat,dog,girls,man
```

The `\s` matches a single space, the `+` means *one or more* of the previous atom, so the combination gives *one or more spaces*.

Answer (score 3):

We dont have to do this much of work.. try this... join will do your whole work.. do not split.. just join...

```
 set string "boy      cat dog            girl     man"
 set string [join $string ,]
```

Comment: Works on this input, but doesn't with some more complex inputs. Which might or might not matter; the questioner does not guide us properly.

Comment: I completely agree with you @DonalFellows. I just focused on given input.. In that case Marco answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use `split` to separate your original (space-delimited) string into a list of words, and `join` to make a comma-delimited string

```
set original "boy cat dog girl man"

set l [split $original]
set final [join $l ,]
```

This works fine for your example but wouldn't handle cases where your original string didn't correspond properly to Tcl's notion of a list. It also wouldn't cope with converting, say,

```
boy cat dog girl man "Aunt Sally"
```

into

```
boy,cat,dog,girl,man,"Aunt Sally"
```

If you want to handle this case, take a look at the [csv](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/csv.html) package - in particular `csv::split` and `csv::join`.

Comment: `split` works on strings, not lists, so no problem there. It will give you empty elements where there's multiple spaces though.

Comment: You would have to use [`textutil::split::splitx`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_split.html) to split on arbitrary whitespace, and that uses regexp in the background anyway.